# Python lookup multiple values based on timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, timestamp

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'from': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
     'to': ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple'],
     'month': ['Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18','Sep-18']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

out:

```
     from      to    month
0   apple  banana   Aug-18
1  banana  orange   Aug-18
2  orange   apple   Aug-18
3  banana  orange   Sep-18
4   apple  banana   Sep-18
5  orange   apple   Sep-18
```

I have a CSV reference table/lookup table that looks like this:

```
product  start_date  end_date   weight grade
apple    01/06/2018  31/08/2018 heavy   a
orange   01/06/2018  31/08/2018 heavy   c
banana   01/06/2018  31/08/2021 heavy   b
apple    01/09/2018  31/12/2021 small   a
orange   01/09/2018  31/12/2021 heavy   a
```

Note: in the reference/lookup the dimensions can change from month to month.

I need to insert 4 new columns in my dataframe called: (1) from_weight, (2) to_weight, (3) from_grade (4) to_grade. And merge values in the dataframe with the reference table based on a timestamp to get this result:

```
     from      to    month     from_weight to_weight from_grade to_grade
 0   apple  banana   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          a        b
 1  banana  orange   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          b        a
 2  orange   apple   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          a        a
 3  banana  orange   Sep-18       heavy     heavy          b        a
 4   apple  banana   Sep-18       small     heavy          a        b
 5  orange   apple   Sep-18       heavy     small          a        a
```

Comment: Did you try any code yourself? What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: Can you explain more how output table is created?

Comment: I would convert the start date on the csv file to a similar format to that in your data frame, and attempt to merge twice, once for the 'from' and start_date and then for the 'to' and end_date. Conversely, you could write a loop to look up the corresponding values in the csv file if your data is small.

Comment: What is your locale? `Sept` is not a standard abbreviation of September.

Comment: My difficulty is I do not know where to start. The output table should insert 4 new columns in my data frame and then fill the columns with values based in the reference table based on the relevant month. For example, for 'apples' in August return weight=heavy for 'apples' in September weight=small

Answer (score 0):

Hope this covers all situations, but can't be exactly sure with only the example provided. I suppose the "CSV reference" always starts/ends in the first/last day of the month (otherwise you have to tell us how to handle those situations).

`grade.csv`:

```
product,start_date,end_date,weight,grade
apple,01/06/2018,31/08/2018,heavy,a
orange,01/06/2018,31/08/2021,heavy,c
banana,01/06/2018,31/08/2021,heavy,b
apple,01/09/2018,01/01/2021,small,a
orange,01/06/2018,31/08/2021,heavy,a
```

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser
import datetime as dt

d = {'from': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
     'to': ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple'],
     'month': ['Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sept-18', 'Sept-18','Sept-18']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=list(d.keys()) + ['from_weight', 'to_weight', 'from_grade', 'to_grade'])

grade = pd.read_csv('grade.csv')

for entry in df.index:
     date = parser.parse(df.loc[entry, 'month'])
     for line in grade.index:
          date_start = dt.datetime.strptime(grade.loc[line, 'start_date'], '%d/%m/%Y')
          date_end = dt.datetime.strptime(grade.loc[line, 'end_date'], '%d/%m/%Y')
          if (df.loc[entry, 'from'] == grade.loc[line, 'product']) & (date > date_start) & (date < date_end):
               df.loc[entry, 'from_weight'] = grade.loc[line, 'weight']
               df.loc[entry, 'from_grade'] = grade.loc[line, 'grade']

          if (df.loc[entry, 'to'] == grade.loc[line, 'product']) & (date > date_start) & (date < date_end):
               df.loc[entry, 'to_weight'] = grade.loc[line, 'weight']
               df.loc[entry, 'to_grade'] = grade.loc[line, 'grade']


print(df)
```

Output:

```
from      to    month from_weight to_weight from_grade to_grade
0   apple  banana   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          a        b
1  banana  orange   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          b        a
2  orange   apple   Aug-18       heavy     heavy          a        a
3  banana  orange  Sept-18       heavy     heavy          b        a
4   apple  banana  Sept-18       small     heavy          a        b
5  orange   apple  Sept-18       heavy     small          a        a
```

Comment: Yes, it should always be the last day of the month. How can I add this: 

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=list(d.keys()) + ['from_weight', 'to_weight', 'from_grade', 'to_grade'])`

when I have used:

`df = pd.read_csv('C:\example.csv', usecols= ['from','to', 'month'])`

Comment: @thor the code I wrote also works if you use `df = pd.read_csv('C:\example.csv', usecols= ['from','to', 'month'])` , the new columns will be added automatically to the dataframe when you first try to use it. The only difference is that we order of the columns will be different. Please accept my answer, thanks.